# How to make a csv dataset from raw images in python?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, machine-learning, dataset

I am making a ML project to recognize the silouhettes of different users. I have a raw image dataset of 1900 images. I want to convert them to a csv dataset with labels being the names of the users. I am currently stuck with the part of converting the images to a numpy array. The code is here

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv


# default format can be changed as needed
def createFileList(myDir, format='.jpg'):
    fileList = []
    print(myDir)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(format):
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                fileList.append(fullName)
    return fileList


rahul = []

# load the original image
myFileList = createFileList(r'C:\Users\Mr.X\PycharmProjects\Gait_Project\data\rahul')

for file in myFileList:
    print(file)
    img_file = Image.open(file)
    # img_file.show()

    # get original image parameters...
    width, height = img_file.size
    format = img_file.format
    mode = img_file.mode

    # Make image Greyscale
    img_grey = img_file.convert('L')
    img_res = img_grey.resize((480, 272))
    # img_grey.save('result.png')
    # img_grey.show()

    # Save Greyscale values
    value = np.asarray(img_res.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_res.size[1], img_res.size[0]))
    value = value.flatten()
    print(value)
    npvalue = np.array(value)
    rahul.append(npvalue)

    #with open("rahul.csv", 'a') as f:
    #    writer = csv.writer(f)
    #    writer.writerow(value)

final = np.array(rahul)
np.save("rahul.npy", final)
```

My goal is to make a data set with 1900 images and 4 labels, currently while making the numpy array each pixel of an image is entered in a separate column. making if 1900 rows and 200k columns that needs to become 1900 rows and 2 columns. Any suggestion or help is appreciated

Comment: What is your _specific_ question? What have you tried, what is your current output, and what is wrong with your output the way it is now? "I'm having trouble" isn't enough detail for us to know how to help

Comment: My goal is to make a data set with 1900 images and 4 labels, currently while making the numpy array each pixel of an image is entered in a separate column. making if 1900 rows and 200k columns that needs to become 1900 rows and 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily open an image and convert it to NumPy using [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # returns np array
```